# How to print datagidview using Crystal Reports in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if exists the way to print data table using Crystal Reports. I would like to know it work.

Comment: Please can you help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to do like this and for printing, crystal report has option to print

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.IO;

namespace CrystalReportWithOracle
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            my_rpt objRpt;
            // Creating object of our report.
            objRpt = new my_rpt();

            String ConnStr = "SERVER=mydb;USER ID=user1;PWD=user1";

            OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnStr);

            String Query1 = "select * from TableName";

            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(Query1, ConnStr);

            DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

            // here my_dt is the name of the DataTable which we 
            // created in the designer view.
            adapter.Fill(Ds, "my_dt");

            if ( Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data Found", "CrystalReportWithOracle");
                return;
            }

            // Setting data source of our report object
            objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds);

            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject root;
            root = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
                 objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txt_header"];
            root.Text = "Sample Report By Using Data Table!!";

            // Binding the crystalReportViewer with our report object. 
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        }
    }
}
```